# How precise is CompareTo() of DateTime in .NET

Tags: .net, datetime

When CompareTo() of DateTime in .NET is called, is it comparing the ticks on a DateTime object to the ticks on another one? How precise is the comparison? I'm fetching datetime2(7) values from a sql database and want to make sure the comparison is ticks-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, ticks are compared. This is how `Equals` implemented in DateTime structure

```
public bool Equals(DateTime value)
{
    return (this.InternalTicks == value.InternalTicks);
}
```

InternalTicks returns field of `ulong` type. So, comparison of DateTimes have same precision as comparison of long type. Single tick represents 100 nanoseconds.

Btw database can store time with different precision - some accuracy could be lost. But there is a trick - you can save `Ticks` value to database. In this case you can restore exactly same .net DateTime object later.

Answer (score 0):

The precision of your database has nothing to do with the precision of the DateTime object.  DateTime objects store an internal tick count of 100ns.  So this is quite precise.  And yes, CompareTo will return false if the value is different by 1 tick.

However, your datetime field may not store a date in that high of a precision (though a datetime2(7) should be precise enough).  So if you store two DateTime's in the database, and they have very short intervals, then the value you get BACK from the database may be the same.